# Ui-Tinymce: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tinymce, angular-ui-tinymce

I have a problem with a plugin ui-tinymce for angularjs.
While I walk by routing angulars (without page reload) error pops up:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined
```

(window.tinymce is undefined)

In contrast, when i reload page - everything is ok.
I'm using tinymce in the ng-template used by ng-repeat

Comment: can you please post the code snippet or plunker/JSFiddle?

Comment: In my experience this happens when you are trying to initialize a tinyMCE that is hidden from view. You're probably doing an ng-show where you should be doing an ng-if.